# Discards qualifiers unknown cause (std::bind() / lambda)

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, stdbind, qualifiers

I don't understand where/why the *qualifiers* gets *discarded*.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

class A {
public:
    void f() {};
};

template <typename Callable>
void invoker(Callable c) {
    auto l = [=]() {
        c(); // <------------------- Error
    };
    l();
}

int main() {
    A a;
    invoker(std::bind(&A::f, a));
    return 0;
}
```

I get a compiler error on the *c();* line:

> error: passing ‘const std::_Bind(A)>’ as
>   ‘this’ argument of ‘_Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args
>   ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {}; _Result = void;
>   _Functor = std::_Mem_fn; _Bound_args = {A}]’ discards qualifiers [-fpermissive]
>            c();

Workarounds I don't understand:

- Define A::f() as const: *void f() **const** {};*
- `bind()` a reference to instance `a`: *invoker(std::bind(&A::f, **std::ref(a)**));*.
- Pass to `lambda` by `ref`: *auto l = [**&**]() {*

g++ version:

```
g++ --version
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3) 4.8.4
```

Comment: You are capturing by value, when you do so, the captured objects cannot be modified. To allow that, you must either capture by reference or declare your lambda as `mutable`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind):

> The return type of `std::bind` holds a member object of type `std::decay<F>::type` constructed from `std::forward<F>(f)`, and one object per each of `args...`, of type `std::decay<Arg_i>::type`, similarly constructed from `std::forward<Arg_i>(arg_i)`.

This means that `c` holds a copy of `a` (let's call it `c.a`), but since you are capturing `c` by copy, `c` is `const`-qualified inside the lambda, and `c.a` "inherits" the constness of `c` when invoking `&A::f` (see end of this answer).

- Making `f()` a `const` member function allows you to call it on a `const` object.
- If you use `std::ref(a)`, `c` does not hold a copy of `a` but a `std::reference_wrapper<A>`, and the way `operator()` works for `std::reference_wrapper<A>` is different (see end of this answer).
- When capturing by reference `[&]`, `c` is not `const` anymore, so you can call a non-const member function on `c.a`.

---

Extra details (still from [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind)):

> If the stored argument `arg` is of type `std::reference_wrapper<T>` (for example, `std::ref` or `std::cref` was used in the initial call to `bind`), then the argument `vn` in the `std::invoke` call above is `arg.get()` and the type `Vn` in the same call is `T&`: the stored argument is passed by reference into the invoked function object.

So the call with `std::ref(a)` is equivalent to:

```
std::invoke(&A::f, std::forward<A&>(c_a.get()));
```

Where `c_a` is the `std::reference_wrapper<A>` stored inside `c`. Notice that the forward type is `A&`, not `A const&`.

> Otherwise, the ordinary stored argument `arg` is passed to the invokable object as lvalue argument: the argument `vn` in the `std::invoke` call above is simply `arg` and the corresponding type `Vn` is `T cv &`, where `cv` is the same cv-qualification as that of `g`.

So the original call is equivalent to (because `c` is const, so `cv` is `const`):

```
std::invoke(&A::f, std::forward<A const&>(c_a));
```

Where `c_a` is the copy of `A` inside `c`.

Answer (score 4):

Great answer by Holt.

If you are not in a position to modify A::f to be a const method, you can make the lambda mutable:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <functional>

class A {
public:
    void f() {};
};

template <typename Callable>
void invoker(Callable c) {
    auto l = [=]() mutable // <-- Fixed
    {
        c(); 
    };
    l();
}

int main() {
    A a;
    invoker(std::bind(&A::f, a));
    return 0;
}
```